# issues with PyPlot color bar tick marks with images

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot an image with a superimposed fitted curve, but for now I'll just provide an example of an image.

I have been following this example ( http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html ), but when I try to replace the gaussian noise with an image the color bar tick marks don't display correctly (i.e they are all smashed down at the left end).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)
#data = Image.open('testTop.tif')

cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.afmhot)
ax.set_title('colorBar fun')

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1], orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(['Low', 'Medium', 'High'])# horizontal colorbar

plt.show()
```

[image: correct colorbar]

```
#data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)
data = Image.open('testTop.tif')
```

[image: incorrect colorbar]

Is there something intrinsic about displaying images that skews the colorbar, or is there something else obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colorbar axis only goes from -1 to 1 in the example with the random nose because the data ranges from -1 to 1. The tif image your using probably has a different range of values. You can get the minimum and maximum values of the data you're plotting and use that to set the color bar ticks. Here's an example that will work with both the random data and an image:

```
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

# Load sample image 
image_file = cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.png')
data = plt.imread(image_file)
data = data[:,:,0]  # Take only one channel for a grey scale image. 

#data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.afmhot)
ax.set_title('colorBar fun')

dataMin = np.amin(data)
dataMax = np.amax(data)
mid = ((dataMax - dataMin) / 2) + dataMin
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[dataMin, mid, dataMax], orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(['Low', 'Medium', 'High'])# horizontal colorbar

plt.show()
```

[image: image with color bar with ticks]

Comment: Thank you, that was a very good answer.

What is the advantage of using
`image_file = cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.png')`
`data = plt.imread(image_file)`
instead of using :
`data = Image.open('testTop.tif')` ?

If I understand correctly, `imageFile = cbook.get_sample_data('string')` returns a file path and `plt.imread(imageFile)` opens that file path, but when I try to use it I get the following error :

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/sample_data/testTop.tif'`

Comment: There's no advantage and you shouldn't use it with your data. It's just a way to load a sample image that I thought was installed with Matplotlib but apparently you don't have it. That image and get_sample_data are part of [cbook](http://matplotlib.org/api/cbook_api.html) and shows up in some of the Matplotlib [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo_clip_path.html). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ah I see, it works with `'grace_hopper.png'`, but not with my own data (thus leading to my confusion), thanks for the clarification.